# Custom sort by meta fields , woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

By echo values I have the right ones, which means wordpress initalize recommended sort but still It does not work.
My custom fields are Numeric type and filled

```
function custom_sort_by_recommended( $sort_args ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && $_GET['orderby'] == 'recommended' ) {
        // Read cookie values for diameter
        $min_diameter = isset( $_COOKIE['Min_Diameter'] ) ? intval( $_COOKIE['Min_Diameter'] ) : 0;
        $max_diameter = isset( $_COOKIE['Max_Diameter'] ) ? intval( $_COOKIE['Max_Diameter'] ) : PHP_FLOAT_MAX;

        echo("Min");
        echo($min_diameter);
        echo("Max");
        echo($max_diameter);
        
        // Read cookie values for offset
        $min_offset = isset( $_COOKIE['Min_Offset'] ) ? intval( $_COOKIE['Min_Offset'] ) : 0;
        $max_offset = isset( $_COOKIE['Max_Offset'] ) ? intval( $_COOKIE['Max_Offset'] ) : PHP_FLOAT_MAX;

        // Modify the query args
        $sort_args['meta_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => '_diameter',
                    'value'   => array( $min_diameter, $max_diameter ),
                    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => '_offset',
                    'value'   => array( $min_offset, $max_offset ),
                    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                )
            )
        ); 

        // Custom sorting order
        $sort_args['orderby'] = 'rand'; // Sort by random to apply the custom filters
        $sort_args['order']   = 'ASC';  // Randomize the results
    }

    return $sort_args;
}
```

What may be wrong here and why It doesn't working as planned.

Idea behind is , offer user Wheels for his diameter which are min and max and display those first , but don't hide other sizes, just move them to the last page.

When I run this Query ON SQL it gives me the output I want

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wheel_universe_posts.ID, mtd.meta_value, mto.meta_value

FROM wheel_universe_posts 
LEFT JOIN wheel_universe_postmeta mtd ON wheel_universe_posts.ID = mtd.post_id and mtd.meta_key = '_diameter'
LEFT JOIN wheel_universe_postmeta mto ON wheel_universe_posts.ID = mto.post_id and mto.meta_key = '_offset'

where post_type = 'product' and mtd.meta_value is not null and mto.meta_value is not null

ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(mtd.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 24 AND 26 and
             CAST(mto.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 8 AND 40 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing your generated query? For example, with something like: `$wpObj = new WP_Query($sort_args); var_dump($wpObj->request)`? When you do that, how is that generated query different from the one which would, if you made it on your own, return results you want to see?

Comment: @FiddlingAway doesn't make any sense, I've echod query inside my function and it says like this https://pastebin.com/rXrx51mq . Diameter and offset and right values but I want to sort by this not filter.

Comment: If you want to sort by `_diameter` and `_offset`, that's not present in your query builder - your `$sort_args['orderby']` is `rand`. With your filters, you're effectively hiding everything else, even though at the end of your question you say "but don't hide other sizes, just move them to the last page". Am I correct in understanding that you want to do something like: 1) have a randomized sorting of entries which have a diameter or offset which matches given values (e.g. between 19 and 21, or between 35 and 45), 2) make those entries a priority 3) everything else goes after that, randomly?

Comment: @FiddlingAway yes, that is correct
Consider like this, you want to buy yourself wheels at https://wheeluniverse.com/ you will pick YMM and hit search. It should first sort you the best fitment wheels which is  diameter 19-21 and offset 35-45 those are best fits and goes to top of search, but instead going ascending 19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,21 i would use rand here so they go 19,21,20,21.... Same rule applies for offset.

Comment: @FiddlingAway why I don't want to filter ? Thats because those are just best pick. It doesn't mean person can put 16" but he should be seeing those on last pages. And yes only change in your example is (e.g. diameter between 19 and 21, AND offset between 35 and 45).  ( AND instead of OR )

Comment: @FiddlingAway I've added a complete SQL in my post.